# BIRT embedded fonts how to remove them

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, birt

I've got short question. I can't find answer in BIRT documentation. How can I prevent user from using BIRTs embedded fonts in fields on report?

In other words I want to remove from that list these fonts that are not avaiable in client OS.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. With "user", do you mean the recipient of the final report (as PDF or DOC or whatever) or the BIRT developer? And: BIRT doesn't have "embedded" fonts. The fonts shown in the drop-down list in BIRT designer are those designed in your OS.

Comment: And if you generate a report as PDF, BIRT will embed (to be more precise: using TTF subsetting) the fonts into the PDF anyway. That way the recipient can view and print the PDF exactly as intended. With DOC and HTML export that's not the case, however.